# Is there a positive displacement compressor that can rival axial compressors in terms of air mass flow to weight ratio?

Tags: power, compressors

Is there a positive displacement compressor that can rival axial compressors in terms of air mass flow to weight ratio?

Comment: Tige Guy is likely correct. but to really answer the question, one owuld have to research weights of bunch of compressors (axial, radial, rotary lobe, scroll, gliding vane, liquid ring ....) for fiven air mass flows have you even started with this? Also axial or radial compressors are for comparativley high flow - low pressure applications so I'm not sure the comparison makes much sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say **No**.

Just because the simplicity of an axial compressor will always beat the complex piston system, unless your prime mover is somehow linear, I guess (A giant on a footplate?). So will centrifugal or screw compressors.  Which is why we only see piston designs for low output, high pressure applications.

Comment: piston compressors are only on of many possible types of positive displacement compressors.

Comment: there are rotary positive displacement pumps